# Alias in docker's ~/.bashrc not found in jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created an alias as a part of my docker image and put the command in ~/.bashrc. The alias is really simple. Just has to run the script that was installed during the image build. When I ran the docker container in my local machine, I was able to see the alias. Also in jenkins pipeline, when I ran the cat the bashrc, I was able to see the alias command. This is my dockerfile.

```
FROM ros:melodic-ros-core-stretch
RUN apt-get update
COPY ./scripts /scripts
RUN cat scripts/alias.sh > ~/.bashrc
RUN bash scripts/install-tools.bash
```

This is how install-tools.bash looks like.

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /opt/scripts
install --mode=755 --group=root --owner=root /scripts/pre-build.bash /opt/scripts/
rm -rf /scripts
```

This is how alias.sh looks like.

```
alias pre-build="bash /opt/scripts/pre-build.bash"
```

This is how the Jenkinsfile looks like.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            args '--network host -u root:root'
            image <private repo from dockerhub>
            registryCredentialsId 'docker-credentials'
            registryUrl 'https://registry.hub.docker.com'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Test') {
            steps {
                sh '''#!/bin/bash
                        pre-build
                   '''
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting from jenkins.

```
Started by user Automated Build Environment
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/<Organization>/test_pkg
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pkg
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
using credential 205a054c-54a3-4cb3-9a7f-519516cc3050
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/<Organization>/test_pkg
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pkg # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/<Organization>/test_pkg
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/<Organization>/test_pkg +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/<Organization>/test_pkg # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/<Organization>/test_pkg # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/<Organization>/test_pkg
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/<Organization>/test_pkg +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 514613afaf7c8be82bd20e219c062f7a4b3fb733 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 514613afaf7c8be82bd20e219c062f7a4b3fb733
Commit message: "Update Jenkinsfile"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 8c840617b0aed9ae50d00700192ed3573bb1c0d4 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
$ docker login -u <private docker hub username> -p ******** https://registry.hub.docker.com
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pkg@tmp/98982a2f-21bf-4460-9dab-d13f8ddba164/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . <private docker hub repo>

Error: No such object: <private docker hub repo>
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . registry.hub.docker.com/<private docker hub repo>
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 125:130 --network host -u root:root -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pkg -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pkg:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pkg:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pkg@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pkg@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** registry.hub.docker.com/<private docker hub repo> cat
$ docker top 657db353b9e3249c87468eafdeae64246f6b2b1ebeb1cd5ed00c618fc8f1691c -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] sh
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_pkg@tmp/durable-e7036032/script.sh: line 2: pre-build: command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] cleanWs
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
[WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
[WS-CLEANUP] done
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 657db353b9e3249c87468eafdeae64246f6b2b1ebeb1cd5ed00c618fc8f1691c
$ docker rm -f 657db353b9e3249c87468eafdeae64246f6b2b1ebeb1cd5ed00c618fc8f1691c
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm trying to find out how to add aliases to docker image that I can access in Jenkinsfile while running a declarative pipeline.

Comment: The trivial solution is always to not use aliases. At all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should broadly assume `.bashrc` and similar dotfiles don’t work in Docker.  There are many common paths to run Docker commands that either don’t run shells at all or run them in a way that doesn’t read dotfiles:

```
docker run --rm myimage some command
```

directly runs `some command` without invoking a shell at all.  Even if you explicitly use `sh -c "some command"` that won’t read shell dotfiles.

You don’t need alias declarations like the one you show, especially in Docker.  Just install the script into some directory that’s already in `$PATH`, like `/usr/local/bin`.

```
COPY ./scripts /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't run `bash`, you ran `sh` with the first command being a comment referring to `/bin/bash` in the following:

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash
      pre-build
   '''
```

If you want to run bash, try something like:

```
sh "/bin/bash -c 'pre-build'"
```

You may also need to configure bash to act like a login shell to get it to process all the normal login files like the `.bashrc`:

```
sh "/bin/bash -l -c 'pre-build'"
```